# kukushi/SideMenu Reveal Menu not working from presented anotherViewController

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I use side menu library "kukushi/SideMenu"

I send data to another tableViewController (ScheduleTableVC)

```
    let navigation = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchedulePage") as! UINavigationController
    let vc = navigation.viewControllers.first as! ScheduleTableVC
    vc.text = ""
    self.present(navigation, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

But in ScheduleTableVC library function

```
    self.sideMenuController?.revealMenu()
```

not working, which must show menu

Comment: What exactly is not working? Please read [ask] to improve your question.

Comment: are you trying to send data from menuSide?

Comment: @AndresGomez, send data from one view controller to another viewController. But when I do it Side Menu not working.

Comment: oooh ok I think that the menuSide belongs your first view, and when you push a new view, this view hans't a menuSide. 
can you show how you built your app?

Comment: @AdakhanAzizbekuulu are you sure `sideMenuController` is not nil? Did you add it to `AppDelegate` as explained in the docs?

Comment: @koen Yes, I did it.

Comment: I think the problem is when I present another view that view goes above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve it with this

```
    let navigation = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SchedulePage") as! UINavigationController
    let vc = navigation.viewControllers.first as! ScheduleTableVC
    vc.text = ""

    sideMenuController?.setContentViewController(to: navigation, animated: false, completion: nil)
```